# Change Python version to 3.4 Anaconda - UnsatisfiableError

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

For a computer program (Powerfactory) that makes use of a Python script I have to change my default version of Python from 3.7 to 3.4. I am making use of Anaconda. I have tried to do this using the following command in my Anaconda prompt:

```
conda install python=3.4
```

When running this code, the following error appears:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict: 
  - pycodestyle -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
  - python=3.4
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

This error has occured for different packages, which I solved by uninstalling the respective packages. However, uninstalling pycodestyle also means I will need to uninstall Spyder, which I need for my daily python-uses.

Would any of you know a way to work around this? Note: creating a seperate Python v3.4 environment is not an option here, as my other computer program (Powerfactory) looks specifically at the default Python version when it tries to run a Python script.

Thanks! 
Nico

Comment: Can’t you then teach spyder to use a dedicated 2.7 environment? Or use a batch program to start powerfactory that somehow tricks it into finding 3.4? Because there is no other way.

Comment: As @deets you need to create a new environment into which you can install your dependencies. `conda create -n powerfactory python=3.4` should work.